# Increasing concentration of products in a reversible reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry

My teacher says it is not possible to add more products to increase its concentration. This is because products are complex ions. Maybe I just misunderstood what she said. Can somebody verify and explain this to me?

Comment: More details would help in order to answer this question. As it stands, it's unclear what's being asked.